# Do while loop starts on wrong point [Java]

Tags: java, eclipse, calculator, do-while, calc

I am quite new to java and very new to do while loops.
I have an issue with the loop, I made a basic calculator and gave it an option to calculate something else after you calculated something. When this option comes and I enter "Y" (upper case) it "restarts" but if I answer "y" (lower case) it goes back to what you chose.

So for example: If I start the calculator I get 5 options, if I choose option number 1 and I get to the end, I get a choice: If I would like to "try again" so if I choose to answer "Y" the whole thing goes back to the "screen" where I get to make my choice on what to do. But when I choose to answer "y" it goes back to the point of my previous choice. Like if I choose option 1 and I answer "y" it goes back to option 1.

I tried to look it up online but could not find anything so either I do not know to use the right keywords or other people do not run into my problem very often.

Here is the calculator, there are a few dutch words in it like calculator or very bad English but none of them matter in any way:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class GEKENMCHINENENE {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        char aga = 'y';
        while(aga == 'y' || aga == 'Y'){
        Scanner antwoord = new Scanner(System.in);
        int aw;

do{

    System.out.println("enter 1 for addition. enter 2 for subtraction. enter 3 for division. enter 4 for multiplication.");
    System.out.println("+------------------------------+");
    System.out.println("|         Calculator           |");
    System.out.println("|------------------------------|");
    System.out.println("|  Press 1 for addition        |");
    System.out.println("|  Press 2 for subtraction     |");
    System.out.println("|  Press 3 for division        |");
    System.out.println("|  Press 4 for multiplication  |");
    System.out.println("|  Press 5 for my social media |");
    System.out.println("|  *credit to creepershelp*    |");
    System.out.println("|        *on pastebin*         |");
    System.out.println("+------------------------------+");


    aw = antwoord.nextInt();

    do{

        if (aw > 5){
            System.out.println("That number is out of range, try aga within the range of 1 - 4");
        aw = antwoord.nextInt();

        }else if(aw < 1){
            System.out.println("That number is out of range, try aga within the range of 1 - 4");
        aw = antwoord.nextInt();
        }else if(aw < -1){
            System.out.println("That number is out of range, try aga within the range of 1 - 4");
        aw = antwoord.nextInt();
        }

        if(aw == 1){
            System.out.println("You choose for 1, addition. Enter your first number.");
        double fnum = antwoord.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number");
        double snum = antwoord.nextDouble();
        double awp = fnum + snum;
            System.out.println("The answer is " + awp);
            System.out.println("Wood you like to reken uit something else? [Y/N]");
            aga = antwoord.next().charAt(0);


            if(aga == 'n'){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }if(aga == 'n'){
                aga = 'n';
                antwoord.close();
                break;
            }else if(aga == 'N'){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }if(aga == 'N'){
                aga = 'N';
                antwoord.close();
                break;
            }else if(aga == 'y'){
                System.out.println("Please wait!");
            }else if(aga == 'Y'){
                System.out.println("Please wait!");
            aw = 0;
            }
        }

        if(aw == 2){
            System.out.println("You choose for 2, subtraction. Enter your first number.");
        double fnum = antwoord.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number");
        double snum = antwoord.nextDouble();
        double awp = fnum - snum;
            System.out.println("The answer is " + awp);
            System.out.println("Wood you like to reken uit something else? [Y/N]");
            aga = antwoord.next().charAt(0);


            if(aga == 'n'){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }if(aga == 'n'){
                aga = 'n';
                antwoord.close();
                break;
            }else if(aga == 'N'){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }if(aga == 'N'){
                aga = 'N';
                antwoord.close();
                break;
            }else if(aga == 'y'){
                System.out.println("Please wait!");
            }else if(aga == 'Y'){
                System.out.println("Please wait!");
            aw = 0;
            }
        }

        if(aw == 3){
            System.out.println("You choose for 3, division. Enter your first number.");
        double fnum = antwoord.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number");
        double snum = antwoord.nextDouble();
        double awp = fnum / snum;
            System.out.println("The answer is " + awp);
            System.out.println("Wood you like to reken uit something else? [Y/N]");
            aga = antwoord.next().charAt(0);


            if(aga == 'n'){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }if(aga == 'n'){
                aga = 'n';
                antwoord.close();
                break;
            }else if(aga == 'N'){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }if(aga == 'N'){
                aga = 'N';
                antwoord.close();
                break;
            }else if(aga == 'y'){
                System.out.println("Please wait!");
            }else if(aga == 'Y'){
                System.out.println("Please wait!");
            aw = 0;
            }
        }

        if(aw == 4){
            System.out.println("You choose for 4, multiplication. Enter your first number.");
        double fnum = antwoord.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number");
        double snum = antwoord.nextDouble();
        double awp = fnum * snum;
            System.out.println("The answer is " + awp);
            System.out.println("Wood you like to reken uit something else? [Y/N]");
            aga = antwoord.next().charAt(0);


            if(aga == 'n'){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }if(aga == 'n'){
                aga = 'n';
                antwoord.close();
                break;
            }else if(aga == 'N'){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }if(aga == 'N'){
                aga = 'N';
                antwoord.close();
                break;
            }else if(aga == 'y'){
                System.out.println("Please wait!");
            }else if(aga == 'Y'){
                System.out.println("Please wait!");
            aw = 0;
            }

        }if(aw == 5){
            System.out.println("Instagram: rubettt, https://www.instagram.com/rubettt/?hl=en");
            System.out.println("Snapchat:  rubet23-1212121");
            System.out.println("Wood you like to reken uit something else? [Y/N]");
            aga = antwoord.next().charAt(0);


            if(aga == 'n'){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }if(aga == 'n'){
                aga = 'n';
                antwoord.close();
                break;
            }else if(aga == 'N'){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }if(aga == 'N'){
                aga = 'N';
                antwoord.close();
                break;
            }else if(aga == 'y'){
                System.out.println("Please wait!");
            }else if(aga == 'Y'){
                System.out.println("Please wait!");
            aw = 0;
            }
        }if(aw == 0){
            System.out.println("Succesfully shut down!");
        }else if(aga == 'n' || aga == 'N'){
            System.out.println("Succesfully shut down!");
        }

        }while(aw > 1 && aw <329108321);

        }while(aga == 'y' || aga == 'Y');


        }
    }
}
```

I tried to have it change "y" into "Y" but that did also not work.
If anyone has got any ideas, please help. I would love to know why this is and how I can fix it. Thanks in advance,

-Rubet23

Comment: What do You mean "Not work"? StackOverflow isn't debuger replacement

Comment: It's hard to find errors in your code because it is really confusing with repeating cases and is hard to read. Instead of trying to find the error, you should probably rewrite the code and before doing so, you should plan it. If you want, I can help but other than that, I can't do much.

Comment: Create a new project and take all of your code out except the do while loop. At the end of your do while loop asks the question and select an option. If it works correctly, start adding your other code back.

Comment: `else if(aw < 1)` and after this `else if(aw < -1)`, don't you feel something unnecessary here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In your journey to become a computer programmer, I suggest that you take some time to learn how to debug your own code. This can range from paper debugging to using a source-level debugger. These are critical skills needed by any software developer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: This is not an answer, just a criticism on the structure of the code**

Your way for entering "yes" and "no" is prone to mistakes because you are reusing the same code over and over again. Make a method that returns a boolean value. for example:

```
/**
 * This method will return true for yes and false for no.
 * It is private, because it is unnecessary for other
 * Classes to use it.
 */
private boolean sayYes(String text){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        System.out.print(text);
        // Gets keyboard input, trims it, and makes it lower case.
        String input = keyboard.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase;
        // Checks for "Yes"
        if(input.equals("y") || input.equals("yes"))
            return true;
        // Checks for "No"
        if(input.equals("n") || input.equals("no"))
            return false;
        // If we got here, then it was neither a "yes" or "no",
        // so we complain, and go around the loop again
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
    }
    // The keyboard Scanner is not closed so the program can
    // continue to receive keyboard input from other places.
}
```

You then can call this method with:

```
if(sayYes("Wood you like to reken uit something else? [Y/N]\n")){
    aw = 0;
} else {
    antwoord.close();
    break;
}
```

This also allows the input system to be more robust, since they are given multiple shots to type in a response, and they can type in complete gibberish without breaking the code. You can also make a similar system for retrieving numbers.

Comment: Rubet23 This is the kind of thing I am referring to in the comment of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set aw to 0 when you check for the lowercase 'y,' so the while loop repeats because you never changed the number. At the very bottom, your code should say:

```
//The stuff above this
else if(aga == 'y'){
    System.out.println("Please wait!");
    aw = 0;
}
//The rest of your code`
```

This doesn't have to do with your question, but I think you should use aga.toUpper() to make the input uppercase each time. This way you don't have to write the same code twice to do both cases; you can just test for the uppercase instance of the letter.

Good luck!

Comment: I believe that my solution will work; however, I do humbly recommend that you take the advice of the commenters above and spend some time cleaning up your code and removing unnecessary lines before continuing on with your project. It will make things easier for you and you'll be a much better programmer for the effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have got two loops that run `while(aga == 'y' || aga == 'Y');`. There is no distinction between the two. If you want the two possibilities to behave in two different ways, you need to use them in two different ways as well.

It seems like it should behave like you want it to when you move one of the comparisons to the other `while` condition:

```
while(aw > 1 && aw <329108321 && aga != 'y');
```

Note that your code is very hard to read because your indentation is ver inconsistent.